# Node.js - Can't understand Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments

I have this 2 files for my example:

app.js - main file

```
var greet = require('./greet.js');
```

greet.js:

```
module.exports = "Hello";
```

So, from my understanding; app.js has a module object by default, inside it there is
an exports property, which is an empty object. now when I call require node does this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) 
{
//load greet.js, return module.exports(but which one? app.js's or greet.js's)
}
```

now, what exactly are those exports and module arguments? do they point at the module object of app.js or greet.js? where does the exports argument point to? and why are they needed if node simply creates
a new module object inside that execution context of that anon function which is triggered by require?
I'd like to get as much info as I can get on this topic.

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Have you read docs https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html?

Comment: Couldn't really grasp it. Not everything is in there.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. You could read source code if you want to know how exactly modules work. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js